# How to access properties of a class from within a class defined as a property of the first class?

Tags: typescript

Say I have 2 classes, SimpleClass and MyChart:

```
class SimpleClass {
    top: number;
    bottom: number;
    chart: MyChart;

    constructor() {
        this.chart = new MyChart();
    }
}


class MyChart {
    name: string;
    public method() {

    }
}
```

Is it possible for the method() of MyChart to access the fields `top` and `bottom`?

Comment: No, you must pass top and bottom as parameter or keep a ref to SomeClass in MyChart

Answer (score 0):

Is the MyChart class always a property of the SimpleClass?

In that case you could pass the SimpleClass as a constructor parameter to MyChart.

This would make a strong coupling between them so depending on your scenario Alexander’s idea of passing the properties you need might be a good option. You could also define a special type to pass into the constructor containing just the properties you need and then create an instance of this pass as a constructor argument.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. How would I pass the SImpleClass as a constructor parameter to MyChart: this.chart = new MyChart(); - what goes inside the MyChart brackets?

Comment: You would do something like: this.chart = new MyChart(this)